# Visio 2003 - Align Connectors

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio, alignment

In Visio 2003, is there a way to align connectors among shapes? I am specifically attempting to correct the issue shown in the image below. When using connectors to imply hierarchy, I do not really wish to see each individual connector, only enough to demonstrate the hierarchy.

Any suggestions? I am currently manually dragging the connectors into place, but this is a tedious process. The image below show the problem on the left, and the desired outcome on the right:

[image: Sample Chart - left: problem right: desired outcome]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this from Visio help:

[image: multi-tree shape]

> From Blocks, drag a tree shape onto
>   the drawing page. If you want two
>   branches, use a Double-tree shape.
>
> If you want two or more branches, use
>   a Multi-tree shape.  Drag the yellow
>   control handle on the trunk to the
>   right to create more branches.